# Using python RE to replace a string in Word Document?

Tags: python

So i am trying to run through a word document to replace all text strings with 'aaa' (just for example) to replace it with a variable from user input, i have been bashing my head with a few answers on stackoverflow to figure out and came across Regular expressions which i have never used before, after using a tutorial for a bit I just can't seem to get my head round it.

This is all the code i have tried exampling but just can't seem to get python to actually change the text string in this Word Document.

```
 from docx import Document
 import re

 signature = Document ('test1.docx')
 person = raw_input('Name?')
 person = person+('.docx')
 save = signature.save(person)


 name_change = raw_input('Change name?')
 line = re.sub('[a]{3}',name_change,signature)
 print line
 save
 for line in signature.paragraphs:
     line = re.sub('[a]{3}',name_change,signature)

 for table in signature.tables:
     for cell in table.cells:
        for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
            if 'aaa' in paragraph.text:
                print paragraph.text
                paragraph.text= replace('aaa',name_change)

  save
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: .docx document is a .zip file containing .xml files. You'd have better luck trying to replace the data in the unpacked .xml file then update the .docx archive with it, or better: use docx python module which is able to do stuff with .docx documents.

Comment: that said, I didn't read your code: you're already using .docx module. My bad :) the issue you'll be having is that your replacement maybe works, but you're not writing the file back to disk, so all changes are lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in signature.paragraphs:
    line = re.sub('[a]{3}',name_change,signature)
```

The above code is redundant since you update the variable `line` with the re.sub, but it doesn't cause an update in the actual origin, as shown below:

```
data = ['aaa', 'baaa']
for item in data:
    item = re.sub('[a]{3}', 't', item)

print(data)
#['aaa', 'baaa']
```

Also, you are iterating over `signature.paragraphs` but just calling `re.sub` on the entirety of `signature` everytime. Try something like this:

```
signature = re.sub('[a]{3}', name_change, signature)
save
```